# Why is my addPoint() not recognized as a function in my highcharts code?

Tags: javascript, json, api, highcharts

I am working with Highcharts and live data. I have my ajax all set up properly it seems and have a setTimeout called to bring in live data. Whenever that data comes in I want to addPoint() to my series and draw the new graph (shifting to the left).  Below is my code, line 85 is the .addPoint call but you will see in the console that it is showing as not a function or undefined.

I know from the console as well that I am a calling my data correctly from my chart (chart1.data.series[0] returns and object).  Here is the highcharts documentation on series data and addPoint : < http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.addPoint >

Any idea where I went wrong? I am new to js 1 year <. so I appreciate all your help!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container" style="width:100%"></div>
</body>
<script>
chart1 = {
    yAxisMin: null,
    yAxisMax: null
};
// empty objects for our data and to create chart
seriesData = [];
BPM = [];
time1 = [];

// console.log(chart1.data.series);

$(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });


        function requestData() {
            var url = 'http://msbandhealth.azurewebsites.net/odata/PulsesAPI/';
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                dataType: 'json',
                context: seriesData,
                success: function(data) {

                    shift = chart1.data.series[0].data.length > 20;
                    // structure our data 
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.value.length; i++) {
                        bpm = data.value[i].BPM;
                        time = data.value[i].Time;
                        console.log(time);
                        this.push([time, BPM]);
                        BPM.push(bpm);
                        time1.push(time);
                    }

                    // console.log(series[0]);
                    // find the highest pulse  so we can set it to the highest y point
                    chart1.yAxisMax = (function(array) {
                        var pulse_array = [];

                        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                            if (array[i] != null) {
                                pulse_array.push(array[i]);
                            }
                        }
                        return Math.max.apply(Math, pulse_array);
                    })(BPM);

                    // find the lowest pulse rate and set it to lowest y point
                    chart1.yAxisMin = (function(array) {
                        var pulse_array = [];

                        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                            if (array[i] != null) {
                                pulse_array.push(array[i]);
                            }
                        }
                        return Math.min.apply(Math, pulse_array);
                    })(BPM);

                    // set our data series and create new chart
                    chart1.data.series[0].data = BPM;

                    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chart1.data);
                    $('#container').css({
                        height: '400px'
                    });

                    chart1.data.series[0].addPoint(BPM, true, true);

                    // setTimeout(requestData, 3000);
                    console.log(chart1.data.series);
                }

            });
        }

        // give highcharts something to render to
        container = document.getElementById("container");

        chart1.data = {

            chart: {
                renderTo: container,
                type: 'spline',
                animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                marginRight: 10,
                events: {
                    load: requestData()
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: ' Real Time Pulse Analysis'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: chart1.yAxisMin,
                max: chart1.yAxisMax,
                title: {
                    text: 'Heart Rate'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                        Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                        Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Beats Per Minute',
                data: []
            }]


        };

    });
});
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: **UPDATE**  had to add moment.js to correctly parse my date's for x axis. addPoint is still not working the way I want it to. I want my points to slide off the chart to the left and enter to the right on the set time out. instead it is redrawing the whole graph at the interval. this is what I am going for:  http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update

Answer (score 1):

You should use reference to chart and then call addPoint, instead of refer to chart configuration object.

Correct form: `chart.series[0].addPoint()`

Comment: How do you use reference to chart? Right now my chart  object is called chart1.data and is made in there. But can you give me an example of how you reference? I'm confused. Thank you.

Comment: You need to reference to variable where chart is kept (chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chart1.data) ), so addPoint need to be called on chart.series[0].addPoint.

Comment: ok that seems to do the trick thank you. the third paramater is set to true and the graph still piles up the data on the screen. Do you know why the shift isn't working??

Comment: Honestly without live demo is difficult to debug it, so please recreate if possible.

Comment: Sebastian, thank you ! here is a link to what i currently have : http://pulse2.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: also, some code i recently added ` shift = chart1.data.series[0].data.length > 20;

                    var sortedBPM = BPM.sort(function(a, b) {
                        return a - b;
                    })
                    
                    console.log(sortedBPM);
                    chart.series[0].addPoint(sortedBPM, true, shift); `

Comment: The problem is that you call requestData function each time and then you initialise chart again and again. Please check the solution like [this](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update) which introduce how to use adding/refreshing points etc.